# PQconnectdb returning NULL, why?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

### Context

I've just installed postgres 9.1.4 on Lion, and i would like to write a simple client in C (libpq) to connect to PG databases.

*psql -l* says that there is a database named *mydb* owned by *postgresDB*.

*psql mydb* says : *mydb=#*

Here the little program that tries to connect to mydb :

```
// Server coordinates
const char * keywords[] = {"dbname", "user", NULL};
const char * values[] = {"mydb", "postgresDB", NULL};

// Check server state
analyse_PQpingParams (PQpingParams (keywords, values, 0));

// Connect to the database
PGconn * conn; 
conn = PQconnectdbParams (keywords, values, 0);

// Check if the connection is healthy
analyse_PQstatus (PQstatus (conn));

// Clean exit
PQfinish (conn);
exit (0);
```

### Problem

Here what the program retuns :

```
analyse_PQpingParams says :
------
The server is running and appears to be accepting connections.
------

analyse_PQstatus says :
------
The state returned was NULL.
------
```

Why is the *conn* object *NULL* ?

### What the documentation says :

*Note that these functions will always return a non-null object pointer, unless perhaps there is too little memory even to allocate the PGconn object.* If it was a memory problem, then *psql* could not have connected to my db. So, the documentation doesn't help here. Maybe elsewhere ?

Many thanks for your answers !

Pierre.

### analyse_PQstatus code :

```
void analyse_PQstatus (int status) 
{
  cout << "\nanalyse_PQstatus says :" << endl;
  cout << "------" << endl;
  switch (status)
    {
    case CONNECTION_STARTED:
      cout << "Waiting for connection to be made." << endl;
      break;

    case CONNECTION_MADE:
      cout << "Connection OK; waiting to send." << endl;
      break;

    case CONNECTION_AWAITING_RESPONSE:
      cout << "Waiting for a response from the server." << endl;
      break;

    case CONNECTION_AUTH_OK:
      cout << "Received authentication; waiting for backend start-up to finish." << endl;
      break;

    case CONNECTION_SSL_STARTUP:
      cout << "Negotiating SSL encryption." << endl;
      break;

    case CONNECTION_SETENV:
      cout << "Negotiating environment-driven parameter settings." << endl;
      break;
    case 0 :
      cout << "The state returned was NULL" << endl;
      break;
    default :
      cout << "could not analyse this status code : " << status << endl;
    } 
    cout << "------\n" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show the `analyse_PQstatus` function? Are you really finding that `conn` is NULL or that the result of `PQstatus(conn)` (which is what you are passing to the function) is 0, i.e. `CONNECTION_OK`?

Comment: @PHF ok, looking at the code: you're not explicitly handling the CONNECTION_OK value in the switch, but interpreting literal 0 (which is "CONNECTION_OK") as "The state returned was NULL". By default PQconnectdb and friends will block until the connection is established.

Comment: The state is just zero ( := CONNECTION_OK) The OP appears to have a tendency to confuse NULL and zero.